# $.ajax function calling from php and json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am retrieving data from a function which is defined in my php file as follows:

**PHP Script - functions.php**

```
case 'interns':
        $final['interns'] = queryInter($conn, $id);
        break;
echo json_encode($final);
```

**Global.js**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "functions.php",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
   action: "interns",
   id: id
   },
   success:
   function(id_interns) {
```

In my global.js, I want to know what does `function(id_interns)` contains and returns ? And also, what does the `action: "interns"` and `id : id` do ?

Comment: write after switch() print_r($_POST);

Comment: `success:function(response) {
console.log(response);
      }` you will get the response from php as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action: "interns"
id : id`

are the HTTP POST values sent to `functions.php`

As for `function(id_interns)`.

This is a callback function which is invoked when your javascript recieves a `response` from `functions.php`.  `id_interns` is the actual response (output of the php page) passed as a parameter to this function.

Whatever code is contained in this function (which you haven't yet posted) is what your javascript does with the response (usually outputs to html in some form, or performs some calculations)

Edit to include comments:

Somewhere in the script it will say `$id = $_POST['id'];` Which is used in `$final['interns'] = queryInter($conn, $id);`  Which then within your returned json will be the key `interns`, with the value of `id`.

Comment: Oh I see. So id_interns contains all the data received from the  function in php. So the action refers to the case statement 'interns' ? and the id ?

Comment: That is how the code appears, you haven't posted absolutely everything, such as the entire `switch()` statement, but it certainly makes sense to make those assumptions.

Comment: If you post the whole php script I can tell you for sure.  But I will put money on that somewhere in the script it says `$id = $_POST['id']; Which is used in `$final['interns'] = queryInter($conn, $id);`  Which then within your returned json will be the key `interns`, with the value of `id`. I will also edit this information into the answer

Comment: Haha.. You win the bet. You''re right, I have `$id = $_POST['id`] in the php script.